# Why is looking for an item in a hash map faster than looking for an item in an array?

Tags: arrays, list, search, hashmap, time-complexity

You might have come across someplace where it is mentioned that it is faster to find elements in hashmap/dictionary/table than list/array. My question is WHY?

(inference so far I made: Why should it be faster, as far I see, in both data structure, it has to travel throughout till it reaches the required element)

Answer (score 5):

Let’s reason by analogy. Suppose you want to find a specific shirt to put on in the morning. I assume that, in doing so, you don’t have to look at literally every item of clothing you have. Rather, you probably do something like checking a specific drawer in your dresser or a specific section of your closet and only look there. After all, you’re not (I hope) going to find your shirt in your sock drawer.

Hash tables are faster to search than lists because they employ a similar strategy - they organize data according to the principle that every item has a place it “should” be, then search for the item by just looking in that place. Contrast this with a list, where items are organized based on the order in which they were added and where there isn’t a a particular pattern as to why each item is where it is.

More specifically: one common way to implement a hash table is with a strategy called *chained hashing*. The idea goes something like this: we maintain an array of *buckets*. We then come up with a rule that assigns each object a bucket number. When we add something to the table, we determine which bucket number it should go to, then jump to that bucket and then put the item there. To search for an item, we determine the bucket number, then jump there and only look at the items in that bucket. Assuming that the strategy we use to distribute items ends up distributing the items more or less evenly across the buckets, this means that we won’t have to look at most of the items in the hash table when doing a search, which is why the hash table tends to be much faster to search than a list.

For more details on this, check out [these lecture slides on hash tables](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1204/lectures/17/Slides17.pdf), which fills in more of the details about how this is done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great description.  I wish I'd had a professor like you when I was at uni.!  Are they your slides too?  They're very nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

To understand this you can think of how the elements are stored in these Data structures.

**HashMap/Dictionary** as you know it is a key-value data structure. To store the element, you first find the Hash value (A function which always gives a unique value to a key. For example, a simple hash function can be made by doing the modulo operation.). Then you basically put the value against this hashed key.

In **List**, you basically keep appending the element to the end. The order of the element insertion would matter in this data structure. The memory allocated to this data structure is not contiguous.

In **Array**, you can think of it as similar to List. But In this case, the memory allocated is contiguous in nature. So, if you know the value of the address for the first index, you can find the address of the nth element.

Now think of the retrieval of the element from these Data structures:

**From HashMap/Dictionary:** When you are searching for an element, the first thing that you would do is find the hash value for the key. Once you have that, you go to the map for the hashed value and obtain the value. In this approach, the amount of action performed is always constant. In Asymptotic notation, this can be called as **O(1)**.

**From List:** You literally need to iterate through each element and check if the element is the one that you are looking for. In the worst case, your desired element might be present at the end of the list. So, the amount of action performed varies, and in the worst case, you might have to iterate the whole list. In Asymptotic notation, this can be called as **O(n)**. where n is the number of elements in the list.

**From array:** To find the element in the array, what you need to know is the address value of the first element. For any other element, you can do the Math of how relative this element is present from the first index.

**For example**, Let's say the address value of the first element is 100. Each element takes 4 bytes of memory. The element that you are looking for is present at 3rd position. Then you know the address value for this element would be 108. Math used is

`Addresses of first element + (position of element -1 )* memory used for each element`.

That is 100 + (3 - 1)*4 = 108.

In this case also as you can observe the action performed is always constant to find an element. In Asymptotic notation, this can be called as **O(1)**.

Now to compare, O(1) will always be faster than O(n). And hence retrieval of elements from HashMap/Dictionary or array would always be faster than List.

I hope this helps.